# Can I detect any type of video playing in HTML using javascript and then pause all media using a function?

Tags: javascript, dom, video, iframe

The application I am helping build is using videos embedded in an iframe from sites like youtube and 5min.com. Is there a way I can write a javascript function in the head of the HTML to detect any type of video, then use pause() to stop the video from playing when the function is called? Right now the function I have is this:

```
function stopPlaying() {
  document.getElementByTagName("iframe").pause(); 
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iFrames, it is not possible. But, if the video is in your page, then you can do it. Check if the you can access the videos, run the following code in you page, if it returns 0, you cannot access the video:

```
alert("number of <video> in this page: " + document.getElementsByTagName('video').length);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Decided to refresh the page. It was a web view for iOS and we are caching pages that are viewed, so if the user swipes to the next page, I wanted to programmatically pause the video. Refreshing solved some other problems, so we went with that. Thanks!